# How to implement role-based authorization to only specific attributes of a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I have an `Accounts` resource (model + controller). Currently, all actions of the `AccountsController` are preceded by the `authorize_admin` `before_action`, which checks if a user is an admin or not and if not - it redirects the user to the `home_path`.

What I now want to do is allow the users to edit some fields of their own accounts. I am not sure how to do this. I have several ideas:

1. In the same Accounts controller create custom `edit_personal_account` and `update_personal_account` actions, with a custom `personal_account_params` (Rails 4, strong parameters). In the `personal_account_params` I will `permit` only the fields that a user is allowed to edit.
2. Create a new `PersonalAccounts` controller with normal restful actions, but only `edit`, `update`, and `show`. This controller will interact again with the `Account` model.
3. Use a gem like `cancancan` or `pundit`. I have skimmed over their documentation and wikis, but so far I have only found examples of how to restrict access to whole actions based on role and not how to restrict access to specific fields.

So my question is - which of the three ways would be most appropriate for my scenario and are there any other better ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
# accounts_controller.rb
before_action :authorize_admin, except: [:edit, :update]

def update
  @account.update(account_params)
end

private

def account_params
  if current_user.admin?
    params.require(:account).permit(<all params>)
  else
    params.require(:account).permit(<subset of params>)
  end 
end
```

This way you would explicitly declare in your `account_params` method which parameters normal users would be able to edit, which may or may not be what you want.

You would also need to hide some of the fields in your `edit` view based on the current user's role (i.e. if she's an admin, hide nothing etc.), but that shouldn't be very hard. You could even create a custom form builder doing so.